# Incrementing in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to simplify my code a bit when I fill in a a Pandas dataframe, for example this works great to auto-increment a string:

```
results['Cluster'] = ['Cluster %s' %i for i in range(1, len(results) + 1)]
```

Result:
Cluster 1
Cluster 2
Cluster 3
etc

How I do the same elegant code when I refer to another dataframe values, all I need to do is to increment cluster_**X** and total_c**X**, rather then refer to each one individually...

```
results['Item per Population'] = [cluster_1.shape[0]/total_c1,cluster_2.shape[0]/total_c2,cluster_3.shape[0]/total_c3]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I got it myself.

First define

clusters = [cluster_1, cluster_2...etc)

totals_pop = [total_c1, total_c2...etc)

then:

```
appended_data = []
for i, x in zip(clusters,totals_pop):
 data = i.shape[0]/x
 appended_data.append(data)
appended_data
results['Car Wash per Population'] = np.array(appended_data)
```

There might be a more elegant way of doing this with results.loc[...] instead.